# how to reach the state in Class component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS so I'm still a noob on this, I'm building a simple React Class compoent for counter just to understand what's going on, what I'm facing is I'm trying to add event listner on a div to increase the clicks counter:

```
 import React from "react";
   class App extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           clicks: 0
       };
       this.myRef = React.createRef();
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       this.myRef.current.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
       this.myRef.current.removeEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
   }

   clickHandler() {
       // here is my problem
       this.setState({
           clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
       });
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div className="my-component" ref={this.myRef}>
               <h2>My Component ({this.state.clicks} clicks)</h2>
           </div>
       );
   }}
```

the problem is I'm getting this error inside clickHandler():

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clicks')`

I tried this:

```
this.setState({
    clicks: this.state+ 1
});
```

but I'm getting a new error `this.setState is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the event listener you assigned via `addEventListener()` is not properly scoped because ECMAScript doesn’t provide autobinding. so I recommend you to re-assign clickHandler function in the constructor to include the correct binding to this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        clicks: 0
    };
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

    /******** LIKE this ********/

    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this); 
}
```

Comment: any time, your welcome